# Open PowerPoint from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, object, powerpoint

So, I made a question a few days ago regarding VBA uses of PowerPoint from Excel, and I've made progress from it, but I'm getting an error and I haven't found an answer here. I hope someone can help!

This is my code:

```
Sub ExportaraPowerPoint()

Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim excelTable As Excel.Range
Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim DestinationPPT As String

Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
'I've also tried using Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application, but same result

Workbooks("def1.xlsm").Sheets("sheetname").Activate
'ActiveSheet.Range("B1:C35").Select
Set excelTable = ActiveSheet.Range("B57:L70")

DestinationPPT = "pathfile to definitive.pptm" 'NOTE: My ppt is Macro Enabled, maybe that creates a conflict? 
'I've double-checked it, by changing the file to pptx, but same error code

Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT) 'This is the line where I get the error

If pptApp Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("No se encuentra el archivo PowerPoint de destino")

pptApp.Visible = True
pptApp.Activate

Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range("Slide name")

excelTable.Copy

pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(link:=True).Select
pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True

End Sub
```

The error I get is (I have to translate it from Spanish, so it might not be an accurate translation):

> Run-time error -2147024894 (80070002). Error in the 'Open' method of
>   'Presentations' object.

I've been at it for a few days, but I find no solution whatsoever.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Pretty sure -2147024894 is file not found..? Check your file path for possible typos.

Comment: Ok... Thank you, that was it. I changed the file to a different folder to make the pathfile shorter and I forgot to change it in the code. Thank you so much!